# Linq :Query Join And Equals( variable) Not Work

Tags: vb.net, linq

```
Dim ID_Section as Int32 = 10

    Dim Query = From Book1 In db.Book1
    Group Join Section In db.Section On CInt(Book1.ID_Section) Equals Section.ID_section _
     And Section.ID_section Equals (ID_Section)  Into Section_join = Group
    From Section In Section_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
    Select 
      Book1.ID_Book,
      Book1.Name_Book,
      ID_section = Section.ID_section,
      Name_Section = Section.Name_Section
```

The error appears in the variable id_Section, since the **Linq** does not accept values ​​from the outside, as it seems to me of course.

Here Error :

```
And Section.ID_section Equals (ID_Section)
```

In SQL Query Use At :

```
Declare @ID_Section int
SELECT        Book.ID_Book, Book.Name_Book, Section.ID_section, Section.Name_Section
FROM            Book LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         Section ON Book.ID_Section = Section.ID_section and Section.ID_section = @ID_Section
where Book.ID_Book =1
```

Comment: And could you tell us the error?

Comment: Replace the second join clause with a where clause.

Comment: I do not want to put them in (Where )

Comment: Then you can't use LINQ.

Comment: Error 3 You must reference at least one range variable on both sides of the 'Equals' operator. Range variable(s) 'Class1' must appear on one side of the 'Equals' operator, and range variable(s) 'Class2' must appear on the other.

Comment: If you set in (Where) , the table Book1 records will not appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Where` on `db.Section` with lambda syntax:

```
Dim Query = From Book1 In db.Book1
            Group Join Section In db.Section.Where(Function(s) s.ID_section = ID_Section)
            On CInt(Book1.ID_Section) Equals Section.ID_section _
            Into Section_join = Group
            From Section In Section_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
            Select
                  Book1.ID_Book,
                  Book1.Name_Book,
                  ID_section = Section.ID_section,
                  Name_Section = Section.Name_Section
```

Alternatively you can apply the `Where` to the `Join` results:

```
Dim Query = From Book1 In db.Book1
            Group Join Section In db.Section
            On CInt(Book1.ID_Section) Equals Section.ID_section _
            Into Section_join = Group
            From Section In Section_join.Where(Function(s) s.ID_section = ID_Section).DefaultIfEmpty()
            Select
                  Book1.ID_Book,
                  Book1.Name_Book,
                  ID_section = Section.ID_section,
                  Name_Section = Section.Name_Section
```